# Sort subset of dictionary keys

Tags: python, sorting

How do i sort the following list B that is a subset of dictionary A, based on A's values?

```
A = {1: 10, 2:20, 3: 15, 4: 1}
B = [1, 3, 4]
```

My solution should be

```
B = [4, 1, 3]
```

since

```
A[4] < A[1] < A[3]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `A.get` as `key`

```
A = {1: 10, 2:20, 3: 15, 4: 1}
B = [1, 3, 4]

>>> sorted(B, key=A.get)
[4, 1, 3]
```

Notice that you can set a *default value* as argument for the `.get` method, such that, if a given key doesn't exist in your dict, you can set a position yourself (e.g. last position or first). For example:

```
B = [1, 3, 4, 11]
>>> sorted(B, key=lambda k: A.get(k, -1))
[11, 4, 1, 3]

>>> sorted(B, key=lambda k: A.get(k, float('inf')))
[4, 1, 3, 11]
```

Or, as highlighted by @jpp,

```
>>> sorted(B, key=A.__getitem__)
```

if you prefer a `KeyError` to be raised if referenced key doesn't exist.